# Delegate method not being called objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I am trying yo pass data of two textfields in secondViewController to  ViewController and set text of labels in ViewController.

But the delegate method for passing data is not being called. I have checked it by putting break point. Hence label text is not changing.

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SecondViewController;
@protocol SecondViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)getText1:(NSString*)str1 andText2:(NSString*)str2;

@end
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
@property (weak) id<SecondViewDelegate>delegate;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()




@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate=_delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textField1.delegate=self;
    self.textField2.delegate=self;
    [self.textField1 becomeFirstResponder];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{


    if ( textField == self.textField1 ) { [self.textField1 resignFirstResponder]; [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder]; }
    else if ( textField == self.textField2)  {


        [_delegate getText1:self.textField1.text andText2:self.textField2.text];

        NSLog(@"%@",self.textField1.text);
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

View Controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<SecondViewDelegate>


-(void)getText1:(NSString *)str1 andText2:(NSString *)str2;
@end
```

View Controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;


@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize label2;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController* sv= [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    sv.delegate=self;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToSecondController" sender:self];
}

-(void)getText1:(NSString *)str1 andText2:(NSString *)str2{

    [label1 setText:str1];
    [label2 setText:str2];


}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've created two `SecondViewController` objects and made your `ViewController` the delegate of the wrong one.

This: `[[SecondViewController alloc] init]` creates an object in code.  This: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToSecondController" sender:self]` creates an object from a storyboard definition.

Don't bother creating the first one, just perform the segue.  Then, implement the `prepareForSegue` method and set your delegate there, using the destination controller (which will be the correct `SecondViewController`).

Answer (score 4):

Try setting your delegate in prepareForSegue method like:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.delegate=self;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is sv here. can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare your `delegate method` in `ViewController.h`. It has already been done in `SecondViewController.h` as the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

## import

## import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

***// Remove this method in ViewController.h file this is call as a simple method for ViewController class***
-(void)getText1:(NSString *)str1 andText2:(NSString *)str2;

@end