# My class conforms to two protocols - how can I set different delegates to each of them?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a class `MapEvents` and it conforms to two different protocols. The first one is defined in the same file as MapEvents:

```
protocol HandleMapPopupBehavior: class {
    func hideContainer()
}
```

the other one is in different file. My class that conforms to it is as follows:

```
class MapEvents: UIViewController, ContainerToMaster, HandleMapPopupBehavior {

    var userProfile: YourFullUser?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userProfile = YourFullUser()
        userProfile?.delegate = self 
    }

    func hideContainer() {
        print("hiding container now")
    }

    (...)
}
```

as you can see I try to assign a delegate here:

```
userProfile = YourFullUser()
userProfile?.delegate = self
```

However when in different class I want to refer to this delegate object (by doing:

```
class YourFullUser: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: HandleMapPopupBehavior?

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        delegate?.hideContainer() 
    }
}
```

)

I'm getting nil on `delegate`.

I believe it's because in my `MapEvents` class I didn't specifically set up to which delegate I want to assign the `userProfile?.delegate` and that the `self` is not specific enough -

so my question is how can I make sure that `userProfile?.delegate = self` refers to `HandleMapPopupBehavior` and not to `ContainerToMaster`?

========= EDIT

Following @Rob suggestion I went through the code to check if I set up the `YourFullUser` more than once. I found this block of code that directs from one ViewController to `YourFullUser`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     if(segue.identifier == "fullYourRequestSegue"){

        if let fullUserDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? YourFullUser
        {

            fullUserDetails.descrLabel = self.descr
            fullUserDetails.photo = self.photo
            fullUserDetails.usernameLabel = self.username

        }
    }
}
```

So I assume I have two `YourFullUser` instances - can this affect my delegate object being `nil` later on?

Comment: Your guess is incorrect, the delegate setup looks fine. The instance that is the delegate responds to both so it can work with both, there is no confusion. Most likely you have `YourFullUser()` somewhere else in the code so you're creating another instance that you haven't set any delegate to...

Comment: `YourFullUser` is a view controller, and the relationship between `userProfile` and `MapEvents` is unclear. But I wonder if you might be dealing with two instances of `YourFullUser` (e.g., that which you manually instantiated in `viewDidLoad` and another that was created from a storyboard during segue or what have you). Show us more info regarding how you later use/transition to `userProfile`.

Comment: This seems to be the most common mistake on SO these days.  Here's a similar question/answer (it's not Swift but the logic is the same): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154531/delegate-method-not-being-called-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> So I assume I have two `YourFullUser` instances - can this affect my delegate object being nil later on?

Yes. The `userProfile` is instantiating a `YourFullUser` that is not hooked up to anything, and you're setting the `delegate` on that instance. Then, when you perform the segue, a new instance of `YourFullUser` is created whose `delegate` is `nil`.

I would recommend retiring the `userProfile` variable entirely. Don't set the `delegate` until `prepareForSegue` and just set the `delegate` for the `fullUserDetails` there.

For example:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "fullYourRequestSegue" {
        if let fullUserDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? YourFullUser {
            fullUserDetails.delegate = self
            fullUserDetails.descrLabel = self.descr
            fullUserDetails.photo = self.photo
            fullUserDetails.usernameLabel = self.username    
        }
    }
}
```

The key key point is that you shouldn't set the `delegate` up front but rather defer this until when `prepareForSegue` is called and the storyboard segue has instantiated the destination view controller for you.

Comment: ok, I'm gonna check it in a second - can you just tell me how to set the delegate in the `prepareForSegue`?

Comment: It's just `fullUserDetails.delegate = self`, right where you're setting the other properties.

Comment: but in that case should I make a var `delegate` in class YourFullUser being the type YourFullUser? or just leave it as it is - `weak var delegate: HandleMapPopupBehavior?` ?

Comment: Leave it as is. If I understand your code snippets correctly, `MapEvents` is the view controller segueing to `YourFullUser`, and thus `self` in the `prepareForSegue` refers to the `MapEvents` instance, which conforms to `HandleMapPopupBehavior`.